# What is the better way to do a complex sort for documents with Elasticsearch

Tags: sorting, elasticsearch, search

I have an index who provide a list of products and I try to sort it by price but to find the good price I have many rules because the price can by provided by customer, group id, promotions, etc.

I use a painless script to do that. It's work but it slow down quite a bit my request. Do you know if it can have a better way to do that or something to improve my script ?

There is the mapping of my index and my query

```
{
  "my-index" : {
    "mappings" : {
      "properties" : {
        "discounts" : {
          "type" : "nested",
          "properties" : {
            "discount" : {
              "type" : "keyword"
            },
            "groupId" : {
              "type" : "keyword"
            },
            "validityDate" : {
              "type" : "date",
              "format" : "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"
            }
          }
        },
        "id" : {
          "type" : "text",
          "analyzer" : "standard"
        },
        "prices" : {
          "type" : "nested",
          "properties" : {
            "customerGroupId" : {
              "type" : "short"
            },
            "customerId" : {
              "type" : "long"
            },
            "price" : {
              "type" : "double"
            },
            "validityDate" : {
              "type" : "date",
              "format" : "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"
            }
          }
        },
        "promotions" : {
          "type" : "nested",
          "properties" : {
            "customerCategory" : {
              "type" : "long"
            },
            "endDate" : {
              "type" : "date",
              "format" : "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"
            },
            "price" : {
              "type" : "double"
            },
            "startDate" : {
              "type" : "date",
              "format" : "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

```
GET my-index/_search
{
  "query": {
    "match_all": {}
  },
  "sort": [
    {
      "_script": {
        "type": "number",
        "order": "asc",
        "script": {
          "lang": "painless",
          "source": """
            def date = null;
            def price = null;
          
            DateTimeFormatter dtf = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd
             HH:mm:ss");
            LocalDate currentDate = LocalDate.parse(params['date'], dtf);

            // Find price by customer
            for(item in params['_source']['prices']) {
              LocalDate itemDate = LocalDate.parse(item['validityDate'], 
              dtf);
              
              if (item['customerId'] == params['id'] &&  
              !itemDate.isAfter(currentDate)) {
                if (date == null || itemDate.isAfter(date)) {
                  price = item['price'];
                  date = itemDate;
                }
              }
            }
            
            if (price == null) {
              // Find by promotions
              for(item in params['_source']['promotions']) {
                LocalDate startDate = LocalDate.parse(item['startDate'],  
                dtf);
                LocalDate endDate = LocalDate.parse(item['endDate'], dtf);
                
                if (item['customerCategory'] == params['typeId'] &&  
                    currentDate.compareTo(startDate) >= 0 && 
                    currentDate.compareTo(endDate) <= 0) {
                    price = item['price'];
                    break;
                }
              }
              
              // Find by customer group
              if (price == null) {
                date = null;
                for(item in params['_source']['prices']) {
                  LocalDate itemDate = LocalDate.parse(item['validityDate'],
                    dtf);
                  if (item['customerGroupId'] == params['priceGroupId'] && 
                   !itemDate.isAfter(currentDate)) {
                    if (date == null || itemDate.isAfter(date)) {
                      price = item['price'];
                      date = itemDate;
                    }
                  }
                }
                
                // If price, try to use a discount
                // else get the default customer group price
                if (price != null) {
                  def discount = null;
                  date = null;
                  for(item in params['_source']['discounts']) {
                    LocalDate itemDate = 
                     LocalDate.parse(item['validityDate'], dtf);
                    if (item['groupId'] == params['discountGroupId'] && 
                      !itemDate.isAfter(currentDate)) {
                      if (date == null || itemDate.isAfter(date)) {
                        discount = item['discount'];
                        date = itemDate;
                      }
                    }
                  }
                  
                  if (discount != null) {
                    price = price * (1 - (discount / 100));
                  }
                } else {
                  date = null;
                  for(item in params['_source']['prices']) {
                    LocalDate itemDate =  
                    LocalDate.parse(item['validityDate'], dtf);
                    if (item['customerGroupId'] == 
                     params['defaultPriceGroupId'] && 
                       !itemDate.isAfter(currentDate)) {
                      if (date == null || itemDate.isAfter(date)) {
                        price = item['price'];
                        date = itemDate;
                      }
                    }
                  }
                }
              }
            }
            
            
            if (price == null) {
                price = 0;          
            }

            return price * params['_source']['unitNumber'];
          """,
          "params": {
            "date": "2023-06-06 00:00:00",
            "id": 1,
            "typeId": 1,
            "priceGroupId": 1,
            "defaultPriceGroupId": 1,
            "discountGroupId": 1
          }
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```